# how to hide the global action popup window?

Tags: apex, javascript, aura

I have a aura component, from which I am calling flow all seems to be working fine except in the background of Flow pop up, global action pop-up is showing which doesn't look good. I tried using $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction"), it is closing Flow popup too. In the screen shot there is a horizontal white bar with close icon which is a global action popup.

[image]

Aura Component:

```
<aura:component
      access="global" implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:availableForFlowActions">
         <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.PopUpBox}" />
          <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="Boolean" default="false" />
          <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="global" />
          <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
          <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
          <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
            <div>
              <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                  <header class="slds-modal__header slds-modal__header_empty">
                  </header>
                  <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning:flow
                      aura:id="flow"
                      onstatuschange="{!c.closeModalOnFinish}"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </aura:if>
        </aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that you've created a dialog box inside the pop up that the global action already provides you.

To fix this, you will just need to amend the code to something similar to the following:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.closeModalOnFinish}" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I am using same component for New(override) and clone. That is why I added dialog box. Will create a new component for clone(Quick action)